# mysqli connect problem

Tags: php, mysqli, centos

This is weird. I have 2 centos boxes, prod (192.168.0.1) and vm (192.168.0.30).
Mysql database sits on prod.
App sits on vm.
From vm, if I type

```
mysql -u user -p -h 192.168.0.1 -D mydb
```

it connects lovely, so port is open and listening on prod
but in app, i do

```
$db=new mysqli('192.168.0.1','user','mypass','mydb');
```

and I get

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [function.mysqli-mysqli]: (HY000/2003): Can't connect to 
MySQL server on '192.168.0.1' (13) in /var/www/vhosts/myapp/httpdocs/dstest.php 
on line 123
```

Both boxes have exactly same versions php, mysql, mysql.so, mysqli.so

Any advice?

P.S. This also happens if I try $db=new mysqli('127.0.0.1',... BUT NOT if I try $db=new mysqli('localhost',...

in case it helps, here is my.cnf on prod:

```
[mysqld]
set-variable=local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

max_connections = 500
max_user_connections = 150

key_buffer = 2048M

query_cache_limit=4M
query_cache_size=64M
table_cache=2048
tmp_table_size=64M
max_heap_table_size = 256M

# users buffers
sort_buffer_size=2M
read_buffer_size=2M
read_rnd_buffer_size=1M

max_allowed_packet=16M

thread_cache=16
thread_concurrency=8
thread_cache_size=128
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M

wait_timeout = 240
interactive_timeout = 240
max_allowed_packet=32M

[mysql.server]
user=mysql
basedir=/var/lib

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: Have you tried to check your firewall ? Maybe a rule blocks the vm.

Comment: can't be firewall if I can do it on command line, can it ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check [here](http://www.filonov.com/blog/2009/08/07/sqlstatehy000-2003-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-13/). It looks very similar to your issue.

**Edit: added blog content for posterity:**

> `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can’t connect to MySQL server on
>   ‘xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx’ (13)`
>
> One of the things I wish I had found in Google faster when trying to
>   figure out why PHP script refuses to connect to remote MySQL server
>   issuing an error SQLSTATE[HY000][2003]Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx' (13)
>
> I am able to connect from local shell, so first thought was if
>   something wrong with recent Zend Framework upgrade, but after a while
>   I figured out that answer is very simple – SELinux was blocking remote
>   connections from PHP scripts executed by Apache web server. The error
>   code (13) at the end of error message means “permission denied”, so
>   that’s the indication to see if you have similar issue or not.
>
> Anyway, login as root and do `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1`
>   to make it work.
>
> Of course, think twice because you make web server a bit less secure,
>   so don’t do that unless you are sure you need it.

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. This is exactly what was wrong, and the suggested fix worked a charm. Thank you.

Comment: No idea why but all of a sudden I had to do this with my centos 7 as well

Comment: To clarify...perform this command on the WEB SERVER.  @Matthew Herbst alluded to that, but did not explicitly say it.  I did it on the DB server first, which didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

If that server is local, then try this first :

```
$db=new mysqli('localhost','user','mypass','mydb');
```

instead of

`$db=new mysqli('192.168.0.1','user','mypass','mydb');`

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

restart mysql service via command line by running the below command:

`service mysql restart`

Comment: Hey - welcome to stackoverflow! A bit more detail in your answer will help the question asker, and others, to understand your solution. For example, what about including _why_ it works instead of just how to solve it? Furthermore, some additional formatting wouldn't go amiss. You can put things in `code blocks` by indenting them with 4 spaces.